# How to add many rules to RewriteEngine

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello I have this rewrite-rule example it makes the following example:

`[http://localhost/project/index.php?url=something]`

on my site I use it to make

`[http://localhost/project/index.php?url=task/add]`

shown as

`[http://localhost/project/task/add]`

This is my code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I need to make 3 other things

1. make url `[http://localhost/project/index.php?url=tasks/view/&page=2]`

   shown as `[http://localhost/project/tasks/view:2]`

   or `[http://localhost/project/tasks/view#2]`
2. then my upload folder named (files) I wanna to redirect anyone get any

   file from this folder just browser
3. download files on upload folder named (files) with custom url like as [http://localhost/project/getfile/1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to remind you that `#` is the 'anchor' part of an url. It is never sent to the server, so rewriting to it is probably not the best idea.

What your existing rule does, is internally rewriting all requests that do not map to an existing file, directory or symlink to index.php. If you want to rewrite urls like `http://localhost/project/tasks/view:2` to be rewritten to `http://localhost/project/index.php?url=tasks/view&page=2`, you'll need to add this rule before the rule you already have. Otherwise the more general rule would match it before the more specific rule can.

I also presume you have your `.htaccess` in your `/project/` directory.

---

> make url `[http://localhost/project/index.php?url=tasks/view/&page=2]`
>
> shown as `[http://localhost/project/tasks/view:2]`
>
> or `[http://localhost/project/tasks/view#2]`

Adding the following rule before your existing rule should handle those urls nicely.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^tasks/view:(.+)$ index.php?url=tasks/view&page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Alternativelly, why don't you simply `explode( $_GET['url'], ':' );` in `index.php` instead of this rule.

---

> then my upload folder named (files) I wanna to redirect anyone get any
>
> file from this folder just browser

If you want to stop all direct requests to `/project/files`, you can use the `%{THE_REQUEST}` trick and the `[F]` (forbidden) flag. If you want to display a custom error page, add an [errordocument handler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument) for the forbidden status code.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /project/files
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

---

> download files on upload folder named (files) with custom url like as
>   [http://localhost/project/getfile/1]

Remember that for every request you send to the server, Apache will match it against a regex in the RewriteRule and either rewrite it internally or redirect the user. To internally rewrite a request to `/project/getfile/1` to `/project/files/1` you can use the following rule. Add it *before* the rule you already have.

```
RewriteRule ^getfile/(.*)$ /files/$1 [L]
```

I encourage you to read [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for mod_rewrite.

Comment: thanks bro but I'm working on custom framework so first i need url like `http://localhost/project/$url:$page` become `http://localhost/project/index.php?url=$url&page=$page`

Comment: then my upload folder named (files) I wanna to redirect anyone to error page to cannot get any file from this folder

Comment: Hello bro i used `RewriteRule ^files/ - [R=404,L,NC]`
cuz `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /files
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]` Not working but it hide everything i need it shown on my sript pages only

Comment: `RewriteRule ^files/ - [R=404,L,NC]` will cause the `/getfile/...` url to produce a 404 error now too. If the `/files` folder is not in your `project` folder, you'll need to make a `.htaccess` in your www-root and add the rule to that `.htaccess` instead.